# Switching from Twitter API V1.1 to Twitter API V2 to send Tweets from a Profile to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, twitter

The model I used to collect tweets from API V1.1 was like this:

```
function Twitter_get_tweets() 
{
  var string_Screen_name = "stakehighroller";
  var string_Consumer_key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
  var string_Consumer_secret = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";

  var spreadsheet_Tweets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tweets");
  spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange(3, 1, 2600, 20).clearContent(); 
  
  var tokenUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
  var tokenCredential = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(string_Consumer_key + ":" + string_Consumer_secret);
  
  var tokenOptions = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: "Basic " + tokenCredential,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    method: "post",
    payload: "grant_type=client_credentials"
  };
  
  var responseToken = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl, tokenOptions);
  var parsedToken = JSON.parse(responseToken);
  var token = parsedToken.access_token;
  var apiUrl = "";
  var responseApi = "";
  
  var apiOptions = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    "method" : "get"
  };
  
  var array_Column_a = []; 
  var array_Text = [];
  var array_Expanded_url = [];
  
  var string_Max_id = 0;
  var int_Line_counter = 1;
  var int_Break_loop = 0;
  
  do
  {
    if (int_Line_counter == 1)
    {
      apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+ string_Screen_name + '&count=200&include_rts=1';
    }
    else
    {
      apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+ string_Screen_name + '&count=200&include_rts=1&max_id=' + string_Max_id;
    }
    responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions);
    
    if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) 
    {
      
      var obj_data = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
      
      for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.length; int_i++)
      { 
        array_Column_a.push([int_Line_counter]);
        array_Text.push([obj_data[int_i].text]);
        
        if (obj_data[int_i].entities.urls[0] != undefined && obj_data[int_i].entities != undefined)
        {
          array_Expanded_url.push([obj_data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url]);
        }
        else 
        {
          array_Expanded_url.push([""]);
        }
        
        int_Line_counter++;
        
      }
      
      if (obj_data[(obj_data.length-1)] != undefined && int_i < parseInt(obj_data[0].user.statuses_count))
      {
        string_Max_id = obj_data[(obj_data.length-1)].id;
      }
      else
      {
        int_Break_loop = 1;
      }
      
      
    }
    
  }while (int_Break_loop != 1 && int_Line_counter < 1000)
    
    if (array_Column_a.length > 0)
    {
      spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange("A3:A"+(array_Column_a.length + 2)).setValues(array_Column_a);
      spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange("C3:C"+(array_Text.length + 2)).setValues(array_Text);
      spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange("D3:D"+(array_Expanded_url.length + 2)).setValues(array_Expanded_url);
    }
  else
  {
    Browser.msgBox("0 Tweets found");
  }
}
```

It worked perfectly, but when I adjusted the requests model for API V2, the data is retrieved perfectly, because when I try to send `var obj_data = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());` to a cell, it tells me that the number of characters are above the cell limit.

The current model is as follows:

```
function TwitterTest2() 
{
  var string_Screen_name = "1310800524619386880";
  var string_Consumer_key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
  var string_Consumer_secret = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";

  var spreadsheet_Tweets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tweets");
  spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange(3, 1, 2600, 20).clearContent(); 

  var tokenUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
  var tokenCredential = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(string_Consumer_key + ":" + string_Consumer_secret);

  var tokenOptions = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: "Basic " + tokenCredential,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    method: "post",
    payload: "grant_type=client_credentials"
  };
  
  var responseToken = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl, tokenOptions);
  var parsedToken = JSON.parse(responseToken);
  var token = parsedToken.access_token;
  var apiUrl = "";
  var responseApi = "";
  
  var apiOptions = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    "method" : "get"
  };
  
  var array_Column_a = []; 
  var array_Text = [];
  var array_Expanded_url = [];
  
  var string_Max_id = 0;
  var int_Line_counter = 1;
  var int_Break_loop = 0;
  
  do
  {
    if (int_Line_counter == 1)
    {
      apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/' + string_Screen_name + '/tweets?expansions=attachments.poll_ids,attachments.media_keys,author_id,entities.mentions.username,geo.place_id,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets.id,referenced_tweets.id.author_id&tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,context_annotations,conversation_id,created_at,entities,geo,id,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,possibly_sensitive,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,reply_settings,source,text,withheld&user.fields=created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,profile_image_url,protected,public_metrics,url,username,verified,withheld&place.fields=contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type&poll.fields=duration_minutes,end_datetime,id,options,voting_status&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,type,url,width,public_metrics,non_public_metrics,organic_metrics,promoted_metrics&max_results=100';
    }
    else
    {
      apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/' + string_Screen_name + '/tweets?expansions=attachments.poll_ids,attachments.media_keys,author_id,entities.mentions.username,geo.place_id,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets.id,referenced_tweets.id.author_id&tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,context_annotations,conversation_id,created_at,entities,geo,id,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,possibly_sensitive,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,reply_settings,source,text,withheld&user.fields=created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,profile_image_url,protected,public_metrics,url,username,verified,withheld&place.fields=contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type&poll.fields=duration_minutes,end_datetime,id,options,voting_status&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,type,url,width,public_metrics,non_public_metrics,organic_metrics,promoted_metrics&max_results=100&until_id=' + string_Max_id;
    }
    responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions);
    
    if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) 
    {
      
      var obj_data = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
      
      for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.length; int_i++)
      { 
        array_Column_a.push([int_Line_counter]);
        array_Text.push([obj_data.data[int_i].text]);
        
        if (obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0] != undefined && obj_data.data[int_i].entities != undefined)
        {
          array_Expanded_url.push([obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url]);
        }
        else 
        {
          array_Expanded_url.push([""]);
        }
        
        int_Line_counter++;
        
      }
      
      if (obj_data[(obj_data.length-1)] != undefined && int_i < parseInt(obj_data.includes.users[0].public_metrics.tweet_count))
      {
        string_Max_id = obj_data[(obj_data.length-1)].id;
      }
      else
      {
        int_Break_loop = 1;
      }
      
      
    }
    
  }while (int_Break_loop != 1 && int_Line_counter < 1000)
    
    if (array_Column_a.length > 0)
    {
      spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange("A3:A"+(array_Column_a.length + 2)).setValues(array_Column_a);
      spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange("C3:C"+(array_Text.length + 2)).setValues(array_Text);
      spreadsheet_Tweets.getRange("D3:D"+(array_Expanded_url.length + 2)).setValues(array_Expanded_url);
    }
  else
  {
    Browser.msgBox("0 Tweets found");
  }
}
```

However, when trying to separate the collected values for each row of the spreadsheet with the respective values for each tweet, nothing is delivered to the spreadsheet. This region is not being analyzed:

```
      for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.length; int_i++)
      { 
        array_Column_a.push([int_Line_counter]);
        array_Text.push([obj_data.data[int_i].text]);
        
        if (obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0] != undefined && obj_data.data[int_i].entities != undefined)
        {
          array_Expanded_url.push([obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url]);
        }
        else 
        {
          array_Expanded_url.push([""]);
        }
        
        int_Line_counter++;
        
      }
```

it is jumping without even trying to analyse inside `for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.length; int_i++)` and delivering the warning about `0 Tweets found` according to:

```
else
  {
    Browser.msgBox("0 Tweets found");
  }
```

I try to use

```
      for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.length; int_i++)
      { 
        array_Column_a.push([int_Line_counter]);
        array_Text.push([obj_data.data[int_i].text]);
  
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tweets").getRange("A3").setValue("Test");
        return;
```

to know if inside `for` is being analyzed, but it's not because nothing value is placed in the cell, so I analyze that inside for the script is not being worked.

What do I need to do so that it doesn't happen and actually create the loop in `for` and be able to deliver the list of tweets? The ways to collect the data in theory are correct because by the tests they deliver the exact values.

Links:

API V1.1:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

API V2:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets

**I reinforce that in API V1.1 the data was delivered perfectly.**

V1.1 test result:

[image]

Comment: Still waiting for the application to be reviewed by twitter before having access to the API which might take a while. In the mean time, can you provide the response instead of v1.1 and v2 so it would be easier for other people with no access to the api to test your code?

Comment: Hi @ASyntuBU thanks in advance, the only problem with copying the response is that the value is too large and I can't send the full value to a cell in the spreadsheet and in ```Logger.log(obj_data)``` the full response doesn't appear, it only shows a part completed with ```...```, I would like to help by publishing, but I don't know how I can go about collecting this value.

Comment: @ASyntuBU I can approve access to the original script with the data for API access, I use the account for testing and here is a serious community, I don't see any problems in approving access via email for anyone who wants to help with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of responses differ and you need to actually modify a little for your v2.

Update your loop condition.

#### Modifications:

- `obj_data` in v2 contains additional `meta`, thus you need to get the length of `obj_data.data` instead of just `obj_data`

```
// from: obj_data.length
for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.length; int_i++) {

// to: obj_data.data.length
for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.data.length; int_i++) {
```

- After this, you should be able to get the length which is 100.
- Next problem is that there were entries that didn't have `url` under `entities`. Thus you need to check if `entities.url` exists first before accessing `entities.url[0]`. This will skip those rows url, BUT at least it won't error.

```
// from: 
if (obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0] != undefined && obj_data.data[int_i].entities != undefined)

// to: added obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls to check if it exists
if (obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls && obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0] != undefined && obj_data.data[int_i].entities != undefined)
```

#### Resulting Snippet:

```
if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  var obj_data = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());

  for (var int_i = 0; int_i < obj_data.data.length; int_i++) {
    array_Column_a.push([int_Line_counter]);
    array_Text.push([obj_data.data[int_i].text]);
        
    if (obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls && obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0] != undefined && obj_data.data[int_i].entities != undefined)
      array_Expanded_url.push([obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url]);
    else
      array_Expanded_url.push([""]);

    int_Line_counter++;
  }
      
  ...
```

#### Output:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

#### Entry 79, no `entities.url`

[image: output3]

Comment: I would like to take just one more question if possible, in version 1.1 even the maximum tweets collected at a time, I could collect up to 1000 (one thousand) tweets according to the looping created.

Could you tell me if it's still possible to do this or now there's no way to do it anymore? THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR EVERYTHING!

Comment: No problem @BrondbyIF, I'll try to check if I can do 1000.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: by the documentation I saw, 100 is the max value for maxResult, and without it, 10 is default based on my tests. But you can try check [pagination](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/pagination), maybe you can try something out.

Comment: OK no problem. Thank you very much for the information. I used an add-on in the spreadsheet that can pull up to a thousand tweets, so I believe there is a looping model that can do that.

Or maybe I need to use the tweet search instead of trying to collect directly from the person's profile, I'll give it a study, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome @BrondbyIF, glad that I was able to help you. Good luck.